# How to convert list getting from future method to Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: list, flutter, dart, async-await, hashmap

I want to convert the list coming from `getPosts` method (getting result from the web json and stored in the posts list) to List

**Post Class**

```
class Post {
  final int userId;
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String body;

  Post(this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.body);
 
}
```

```
   Future<List<Post>> getPosts() async {
    var data = await http
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    var jasonData = json.decode(data.body);
    List<Post> posts = [];

    for (var i in jasonData) {
      Post post = Post(i["userId"], i["id"], i["title"], i["body"]);
      posts.add(post);
    }


    return posts;
  }
```

I tried to put the result directly to this method

```
  static List<Map> convertToMap({List myList }) {
    List<Map> steps = [];
    myList.forEach((var value) {
      Map step = value.toMap();
      steps.add(step);
    });
    return steps;
  }
```

but it's not working, I see this error

```
The argument type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
```

Comment: Why put it in a map list?

Comment: @lsaudon I wanna store it to push it to firestore collection, it's need to be `Map<String, dynamic>`

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I don't think you should do it by hand.
Look https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable

Comment: `id` is `int` not a `String`

Comment: @lsaudon I tried your method but I think the issue is with Future, I see this `The argument type 'Future<List<Post>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'.`

Comment: @lsaudon I'll try this library thank you

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. You said you want to do X, yet in your code I see no attempt to do X. You have not even posted the lines where you do what you want to do. Where the error supposedly occurs. We cannot help you by speculating what code you *may* have written and then telling you what errors you *may* have made in that code we think you maybe wrote. Please post a fully working example that demonstrates the error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Change `List<Map>` by `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

```dart
  static List<Map<String, dynamic>> convertToMap({List myList }) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> steps = [];
    myList.forEach((var value) {
      Map step = value.toMap();
      steps.add(step);
    });
    return steps;
  }
```